# What does a cast from byte buffer to a struct do?

Tags: c++, windows, readprocessmemory

I am trying to understand the following code.

```
PLOADED_IMAGE ReadRemoteImage(HANDLE hProcess, LPCVOID lpImageBaseAddress) {

BYTE* lpBuffer = new BYTE[BUFFER_SIZE];

BOOL bSuccess = ReadProcessMemory
    (
    hProcess,
    lpImageBaseAddress,
    lpBuffer,
    BUFFER_SIZE,
    0
    );

if (!bSuccess)
    return 0;   

PIMAGE_DOS_HEADER pDOSHeader = (PIMAGE_DOS_HEADER)lpBuffer;

PLOADED_IMAGE pImage = new LOADED_IMAGE();

pImage->FileHeader = 
    (PIMAGE_NT_HEADERS32)(lpBuffer + pDOSHeader->e_lfanew);

pImage->NumberOfSections = 
    pImage->FileHeader->FileHeader.NumberOfSections;

pImage->Sections = 
    (PIMAGE_SECTION_HEADER)(lpBuffer + pDOSHeader->e_lfanew + 
    sizeof(IMAGE_NT_HEADERS32));

return pImage;
}
```

The code consists of a Windows API call ReadProcessMemory which asks for a pointer to a buffer where the API call will update it's return. What I dont understand is what comes after. what does the operation

```
PIMAGE_DOS_HEADER pDOSHeader = (PIMAGE_DOS_HEADER)lpBuffer;
```

Do? From all I could tell it is a cast, However I have not been able to locate any structure called PIMAGE_DOS_HEADER. I am starting to think that it is not a cast, which leaves me stumped to what operation this is. This is acompanied further by the next line where:

```
pImage->FileHeader = 
(PIMAGE_NT_HEADERS32)(lpBuffer + pDOSHeader->e_lfanew);
```

From what I gathered lpBuffer is a Byte Array, so what is the role of the () here? How can you add a byte array to something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following Microsoftian convention, the type `PIMAGE_DOS_HEADER` is a typedef defining a pointer to a [IMAGE_DOS_HEADER](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Deployment/System/Deployment/Application/PEStream.cs,74a6abbcc7f5a6da,references) struct.

Therefore,

```
PIMAGE_DOS_HEADER pDOSHeader = (PIMAGE_DOS_HEADER)lpBuffer;
```

is casting the `BYTE *` pointer `lpBuffer` to the more-specifically-typed `IMAGE_DOS_HEADER *` variable `pDOSHeader`, presumably in the hopes that `lpBuffer` is in fact pointing to a `IMAGE_DOS_HEADER` struct (since otherwise you'll be invoking undefined behavior when you try to read struct-member-variables via the pointer).

> From what I gathered lpBuffer is a Byte Array, so what is the role of
> the () here? How can you add a byte array to something else?

They are doing pointer-math.  In particular they are adding `pDOSHeader->e_lfanew` to the value of `lpBuffer`, and then casting the resulting pointer to a `PIMAGE_NT_HEADERS32`.

Comment: In the current version of C++ this code is *always* invoking undefined behaviour. You can’t magic a struct into being via a cast (in practice there’s no issue since people have been doing this since before C++ existed, and system APIs *depend* on this behaviour working; but it’s still strictly UB).

Comment: Dunno what the C++ standard says (if anything) about reading memory from other processes, but in general if you "know" (through some reliable mechanism) that a valid struct exists at a particular memory-address, then it's well-defined to cast a char-pointer (or equivalent) to a pointer-to-that-struct-type and use it.

Comment: “Reading memory from other processes” is a red herring. The memory is in *the current process* (after `ReadProcessMemory`, which is entirely fine). But it’s in a byte array, not in a struct. This is a well-known case where the C++ standard is (currently) deficient and there are proposals to fix it (maybe already accepted into C++23, I’m not keeping track).

Comment: Hmm, if that's the case, it would seem to be impossible to use `struct * MyStruct = (MyStruct *) malloc(sizeof(MyStruct));` in C++ without invoking UB.  Is that the case?

Comment: @KonradRudolph - are use `reinterpret_cast < new_type > (lpBuffer )` UB ?

Comment: @JeremyFriesner Yep, that’s currently also UB. Here’s the paper: http://wg21.link/p0593r5. If you’re curious about the low-level details of this, Timur’s talk is a must-watch: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_qzMpk-22cc

Comment: @RbMm Yes, `reinterpret_cast` is in this case the same as the C-style cast.

Comment: Is there any resource you would recommend to read up on pointer math? Additionally, How come in the Microsoft documentation it's always IMAGE_DOS_HEADER and not PIMAGE_DOS_HEADER. Does the appended P signify that its a pointer?

Comment: Google "C Pointer arithmetic", there are lots of tutorials and such.  The P does indeed stand for pointer (that's just a naming convention that Microsoft likes to use in their header files, btw, not part of the C or C++ languages themselves)

Comment: @JeremyFriesner Thank you. Could you clarify why exactly that pointer math is needed? What is the purpose of adding those two pointers in the macro side of things? Does that addition lead to a new specific section of memory?

Comment: According to ( https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/bb985992(v=msdn.10)?redirectedfrom=MSDN ), "The IMAGE_NT_HEADERS structure is the primary location where specifics of the PE file are stored. Its offset is given by the e_lfanew field in the IMAGE_DOS_HEADER at the beginning of the file".  So in the code you posted, the pointer arithmetic is calculating the location of the `IMAGE_NT_HEADERS` structure in memory by adding the byte-offset specified by `e_lfanew` to the original pointer-to-the-top-of-the-struct.

Comment: Do you have any insight into how you could perform this cast in a language other than c++? For example, I have been trying to implement this procedure in python. Since the PIMAGE_DOS_HEADER is a pointer, could you pass lpBuffer by reference straight to the struct?

Comment: Python doesn't have pointers AFAIK; I think the best you could do there is to hold the data in a binary-string and use the `struct` module to parse out the binary bytes into the appropriate field-values.

Comment: @JeremyFriesner Thank you for the help and insight. Your explanation has helped a lot.

Comment: @KonradRudolph but such type cast formal UB not because code is wrong and can lead to crash/random result, but because *C++* current rules are problematic in this part, and not successfully determined ?

Comment: @RbMm These aren’t mutually exclusive: because the rules are as they is, the code *is wrong*. Whether this is a problem in practice is hard to determine in general. For instance, since `malloc` has been used this way for decades in millions of projects, every compiler handles it well. But in other situations this is not always the case, and at least in some specific situations some compilers do generate code that behaves incorrectly at runtime. If in doubt the programmer needs to consult the compiler and platform documentation, and this information isn’t easy to find even for experts.

Comment: @KonradRudolph *But in other situations this is not always the case* - of course, but i view problem in the exact, full and consistent description. Otherwise there would be no corrections, additions and etc in drafts. in practice always will be case, when we have memory (possible allocated outside the language  at all) but we need interpret this memory as some type T. and do this without any extra code.